# PUG / Express Js - Create Array Format in Pug

Tags: express, pug

I am looking to make a array out of this pug template:

```
each test in profile
 = '["' + test.profile_name + '"],'
```

This currently looks like this:

```
["Reach First"],
["Test Company"],
["Test Company"],
```

I want to omit that last comma and make it look like this:

```
["Reach First"],
["Test Company"],
["Test Company"]
```

Notice the comma missing at the very end. I am not sure hot to omit that last comma in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the index in the iteration, and check for it not being the last one. That would probably look something like this:

```
each test, index in profile
  = '["' + test.profile_name + '"]' + (index === profile.length - 1 ? '' : ',')
```